# Count unique IDs with other criteria

Tags: excel, vba, count, unique, countif

Each assigned label should get the number of Colored Books using its unique BookID with same Name, Month and Color in initialize.

Image of Raw Data:

[image: image of raw]

Raw Data Text:

```
BookID  Name    Month       Color
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
101     Jack    January     Red
102     Jack    January     Red
102     Jack    January     Red
102     Jack    January     Red
103     Jack    January     Red
104     Jack    February    Red
108     Jack    January     Blue
108     Jack    January     Blue
108     Jack    January     Blue
108     Jack    January     Blue
108     Jack    January     Blue
101     Thomas  January     Red
101     Thomas  January     Red
102     Thomas  January     Red
104     Thomas  February    Red
105     Thomas  March       Orange
105     Thomas  March       Orange
105     Thomas  March       Orange
106     Thomas  March       Orange
107     Thomas  April       Blue
109     Thomas  April       Orange
110     Thomas  April       Orange
111     Thomas  April       Orange
112     Thomas  April       Orange
113     Thomas  April       Red
114     Thomas  April       Red
107     Thomas  May         Blue
```

Please know that the BookID will be unending. The BookID starts from 101 up to the last book in a very large library with new books still coming up. So there’s another VBA form that keeps submitting BookIDs along with its data (Name, Month and Color) to a Sheet(Sheet3) and that’s already solved. What I am trying to do is just count the unique BookID with the same Name and Color in a Month from that same Sheet. I am really having a hard time picking up the total count of random unique BookIDs with the same color. Count and Total number of BookIDs displayed in labels are dynamic while Names, Months, Colors displayed in labels are static.

Please look at this desired output below:

[image: ouput1]

If you’re going to manually filter Sheet3 by month, you will be able to see these data and these are the total count of Unique BookIDs in red which are displayed in form labels below.

[image: output2]

Sample Manual Filter in Excel:

[image: Sample manual filter]

I am relatively new to VBA and I do not know how to organize and analyze the code below to get the desired output above. Output above has so many variables to declare in the code because of those many labels. I can have one code that only gets the result of January for Jack and Thomas as long as I can get the logic of how it is done so I can continue getting the results for the next months. If this could be done through a list using ListBox/es which will contain Jack and Thomas in the Name column, counts in the Color columns (Red Column, Orange Column, Blue Column) and Total Count for all Colors in the last column of the ListBox, it will be fine, too.

The code I am stuck with:

```
Sub trial2()
        Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, count As Long, k As Long
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        arrData = rng.value
        Dim sID As Variant, sName As Variant, sMonth As Variant, sColor As Variant
        Dim JanuaryCountJackRed As Double, JanuaryCountJackOrange As Double, JanuaryCountJackBlue As Double
        
        'i cannot declare a specific value for sID here because the whole real sheet has so plenty of BookIDs

        'JanuaryCountJackRed = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( ...)
        'JanuaryCountJackOrange = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( ...)
        'JanuaryCountJackBlue = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( ...)
        
        'Me.JanuaryJackRed.Caption = JanuaryCountJackRed
        'Me.JanuaryJackOrange.Caption = JanuaryCountJackOrange
        'Me.JanuaryJackBlue.Caption = JanuaryCountJackBlue
        'Me.JanuaryJackTotal.Caption = JanuaryCountJackRed + JanuaryCountJackOrange + JanuaryCountJackBlue
End Sub
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using arrays. This will facilitate easier extension of the code, simply by adding new data to the Array(). And
used Dictionary to count the unique BookIDs for each combination
Here's the modified code:

```
Sub GenerateReport3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsReport As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Persons() As Variant, Months() As Variant, Colors() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, startCol As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key As Variant

    'Initialize arrays
    Persons = Array("Jack", "Thomas")
    Months = Array("January", "February", "March")
    Colors = Array("Red", "Orange", "Blue")

    'Initialize Dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wsReport.Name = "Report"

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Populate the dictionary
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        key = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "_" & ws.Cells(i, 3).Value & "_" & ws.Cells(i, 4).Value & "_" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Not dict.Exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, 1
        End If
    Next i

    'Loop through Months
    For i = LBound(Months) To UBound(Months)
        wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 1, 1).Value = Months(i)

        'Loop through Persons
        For j = LBound(Persons) To UBound(Persons)
            startCol = j * 10 + 1
            wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 2, startCol).Value = Persons(j)

            Dim TotalCount As Long
            TotalCount = 0

            'Loop through Colors
            For k = LBound(Colors) To UBound(Colors)
                wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 3, startCol + k * 2).Value = Colors(k)
                Dim ColorCount As Long
                ColorCount = 0
                For Each key In dict.Keys
                    If InStr(key, Persons(j) & "_" & Months(i) & "_" & Colors(k)) > 0 Then
                        ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
                    End If
                Next key
                wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 3, startCol + k * 2 + 1).Value = ColorCount
                TotalCount = TotalCount + ColorCount
            Next k

            'Display Total
            wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 3, startCol + k * 2).Value = "Total"
            wsReport.Cells(i * 4 + 3, startCol + k * 2 + 1).Value = TotalCount
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: le me try be ryt back...

Comment: The first 3 rows where we can see January (first row) Jack (second row) and the colors on the third row gives wrong total for Red and Blue Colors. For Red it says 11 instead of 3, Orange it says 0 just right, Blue it says 5 instead of 1 and Total says 16 instead of 4. And the row of March for Thomas has an Orange 4 instead of 2, the rest are getting the right results as what I displayed in form frames above.

Comment: I can see that this is actually counting the instance of the Color it appeared for a Name in a Month. If you could change something on your code that gets the count of unique BookID with same Color for a Name in a Month. Like what I posted above in red marks. TY

Comment: All right! I used Dictionary to count the unique BookIDs for each combination. Update the code on my last posting.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make do with a `Table` such as is shown in a previous answer, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
*Minor changes in the code could also produce an output where the month entries are listed on the same row, in an elongated table compared with below*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Note: Code edited to be more efficient***

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"BookID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Month", type text}, {"Color", type text}}),

//Remove duplicates to be able to get color count for unique ID
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type"),

//Group on Name and Month
//  then Pivot each group on the colors and add a total column
    colors =  List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates"[Color]),Order.Descending),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Name", "Month"}, {
        {"Pivot", each 
            Table.AddColumn(
                Table.Pivot(
                    Table.RemoveColumns(_,"BookID"), 
                    List.Distinct([Color]),
                    "Color","Name", List.Count)
                ,"Total",(r)=>List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(Record.RemoveFields(r,{"Month"}))))
             }
        }),        
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Pivot", colors & {"Total"}),
    #"All Months" = List.Distinct(#"Expanded Pivot"[Month]),
    #"Add Missing Months" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Pivot",{"Name"},{
        {"Missing Months", (t)=>
            let 
                #"Missing" = List.RemoveMatchingItems(#"All Months",t[Month]),
                #"Add Blank Records" = 
                    List.Accumulate(
                        #"Missing",
                        {}, (s,c)=>
                         s & {Record.FromList(
                                List.Combine({{t[Name]{0}}, {c}, List.Repeat({0},List.Count(colors)+1)}), 
                                Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Pivot"))}),
                #"Add Rows" = Table.FromRecords(Table.ToRecords(t) & #"Add Blank Records")
            in #"Add Rows"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Missing Months",{"Name"}),
    #"Expanded Missing Months" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Missing Months", 
       Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Pivot")),
    #"Replaced Nulls with Zeros" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Missing Months",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,colors),
    
    xForms = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Nulls with Zeros"), each if List.Contains(colors & {"Total"},_) 
                then {_, Int64.Type} else {_, type text}),
    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Nulls with Zeros",xForms),

//Add Month Number Column
//  Then sort by Month Number and Name
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Set Data Types", "monthNum", each Date.Month(Date.From([Month] & "-2000")), Int64.Type),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom",{{"monthNum", Order.Ascending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"monthNum"})
    
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

***Results from your data***
[image]

Comment: i will try this. ill give update once i am done. ty

Comment: @Shiela I have edited the code to be moreefficient in creating this kind of output. It can also adapt to increased numbers of `Name` and different `Colors`.

Comment: thank you, this is a whole new learning for me.

Answer (score 1):

- If `BookID` will be continuously increasing, using `ADO` is an excellent choice for handling large data sets.
- You have the option to store the ADO SQL string in a cell if you prefer not to concatenate it within the code.
- The fields' name (column headers) in SQL should be updated if your data is different with samples.
- It is feasible to pivot the color column by manipulating the ADO record set without the need for a `Support` sheet.
- The sole method to retrieve the column header of a ListBox is by utilizing `RowSource`, as you have previously discussed in your posts.

```vb
' ** Code in Userform module **
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 6
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "50,50,40,40,40,40"
        .RowSource = Get_ADO_Data()
    End With
End Sub


' ** Code in standard module **
Option Explicit
Function Get_ADO_Data()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim rngData As Range, Sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim arrData, arrRes
    Const COL_COUNT = 6
    Const SRC_SHT_NAME = "Sheet1" ' Modify as needed
    Const DES_SHT_NAME = "Support"
    ' ADO setting
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" & _
        ";Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    ' SQL to get agg. fields
    strSql = " SELECT T3.Month, T3.Name, T3.Color, IIF(T5.CNT IS NULL, 0, T5.CNT) FROM  " & _
        " (SELECT T0.*, T1.*, T2.* FROM  " & _
        " (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM [#DB$]) T0 , " & _
        " (SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM [#DB$]) T1 , " & _
        "(SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM [#DB$] UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT ""Total"" FROM [#DB$]) T2) T3 LEFT JOIN " & _
        " ( SELECT Name, Month, Color, COUNT(1) AS CNT " & _
        " FROM (SELECT BookID, Name, Month, Color " & _
        " FROM [#DB$] GROUP BY BookID, Name, Month, Color) T4  " & _
        " GROUP BY Name, Month, Color " & _
        "  UNION ALL  " & _
        " SELECT Name, Month, ""Total"" as Color, COUNT(1) AS CNT " & _
        " FROM (SELECT BookID, Name, Month, Color " & _
        " FROM [#DB$] GROUP BY BookID, Name, Month, Color) T4  " & _
        " GROUP BY Name, Month ) T5 " & _
        " ON T3.Name=T5.Name AND T3.Month=T5.Month AND T3.Color=T5.Color " & _
        " ORDER BY T3.Month, T3.Name, T3.Color "
    strSql = Replace(strSql, "#DB", SRC_SHT_NAME)
    rs.Open strSql, conn
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Sht = Sheets(DES_SHT_NAME)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Sht.Cells.Clear
    Else
        Set Sht = Sheets.Add
        Sht.Name = DES_SHT_NAME
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sht.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rngData = Sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To COL_COUNT, 1 To UBound(arrData))
    ' Get table header
    arrRes(1, 1) = "Month"
    arrRes(2, 1) = "Name"
    For i = 3 To COL_COUNT - 1
        arrRes(i, 1) = arrData(i - 2, 3)
    Next
    arrRes(COL_COUNT, 1) = "Total"
    k = 2
    ' Pivot Color column
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData) Step 4
        arrRes(1, k) = arrData(i, 1)
        arrRes(2, k) = arrData(i, 2)
        For j = 0 To 3
            arrRes(j + 3, k) = arrData(i + j, 4)
        Next j
        k = k + 1
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To COL_COUNT, 1 To k - 1)
    ' Write data to sheet
    Set rngList = rngData.Cells(1).Offset(0, rngData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(k - 1, COL_COUNT)
    rngList.Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    ' Hidden sheet if needed
    Sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Get_ADO_Data = Sht.Name & "!" & rngList.Offset(1).Resize(k - 2).Address
End Function
```

[image]

`Support` Sheet:

[image]

Comment: yes be right back i will do this later for i am still in groceries

Comment: hi, The code has created a new sheet named Support but i get an error pointing at `ReDim arrRes(1 To COL_COUNT, 1 To UBound(arrData))` saying type mismatch.

Comment: The code is tested with sample data in OP. You have to update sql if you change the column headers.  Please share your revised code. Is there any data on new sheet?